# Install SharePoint 2013 Foundation on 32 bit system

Tags: installation, windows-server, prerequisites

Is this possible?
There is only one download where neither 64 or 32 is stated (but it definitely runs on 64 bit. So it is either a 64/32 bit combined or 32 bit is not supported).

Second, it requires Windows Server 2008 or 2012 where the former has a 32 bit version but the latter not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SharePoint is a 64-bit product only. It requires a 64-bit OS.
See https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc262485.aspx#hwforwebserver for more details on prerequisites.